# git add files within folders with @ sign - fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, github

I want to add folders that have @ signs in their names. I cannot rename them due to program limitations but neither can I add them to my github repository.

The folder names are:

```
zoteroOpenOfficeIntegration@zotero.org
zoteroWinWordIntegration@zotero.org
```

The git error message is:

```
G:\PortableApps\PortableApps\GitPortable\Data\home\github\PortableApps>git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Zotero Standalone/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

G:\PortableApps\PortableApps\GitPortable\Data\home\github\PortableApps>git add "
Zotero Standalone"
fatal: Not a git repository: Zotero Standalone/ZoteroStandalonePortable/App/Zote
ro Standalone/extensions/zoteroWinWordIntegration@zotero.org/../../.git/modules/
modules/zotero-word-for-windows-integration
```

Is there any solution to add files within folders with @ signs to a git repository?

Comment: what's the exact command? I can add files (you don't add folders in git, only files) which are in a directory containing a "@"

Comment: Hi Charles. I added the complete git procedure to the the inital post.

Comment: you're adding a directory *containing itself* a git repository, this isn't right. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Now it is clear. The extension folders that I was trying to add indeed contained a .git file. I put them in my .gitignore and now I can successfully push the folders. Thus, it does not have anything to do with the @ signs. Good to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing isn't related to the `@` character in the folder, but to the fact that you're trying to add a repository to another repository. Instead you should add it as a submodule.